# Few examples with HTML SIMPLE DOM

Tags: php, html, date, dom

i have some problems with html simple dom and dont know how to get some specific data, i read manual and try by my self, but it looks i miss something so hope somebody can help me.

1th problem:

HTML:

```
<div>
                        <h4>Režie:</h4>
                        <span data-truncate="60">
                            <a href="/tvurce/3074-ridley-scott/">Ridley Scott</a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h4>Scénář:</h4>
                        <span data-truncate="60">
                            <a href="/tvurce/50383-william-monahan/">William Monahan</a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h4>Kamera:</h4>
                        <span data-truncate="60">
                            <a href="/tvurce/66939-john-mathieson/">John Mathieson</a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h4>Hudba:</h4>
                        <span data-truncate="60">
                            <a href="/tvurce/62400-harry-gregson-williams/">Harry Gregson-Williams</a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

My PHP code:

```
$ret = $html->find('span[data-truncate*="60"]');                        //rezia

foreach ($ret as $rezia) {
  echo "rezia <br/>";
  }
```

But this code print just name and a href from all of this name, and what i need is just name which is under "REŽIE"(Ridley Scott) and "Scénář" (William Monahan)

2th Problem
HTML:

```
<div id="rating">
        <h2 class="average">71%</h2>
        <p class="charts">
```

PHP code:

```
$percenta = $html->find('h2[class*="average"]');                        //pocet ˇ%

foreach ($percenta as $hodnotenie) {
    echo "$hodnotenie";
      }
```

What i get from this is 71% and i want just number, not that HTML around, is it possible?

3th problem (the last one:P):

HTML:

```
<table>

                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            V kinech ČR
                             od:
                                                    </th>
                        <td class="date">
                            06.05.2005 
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            V kinech SR
                             od:
                                                    </th>
                        <td class="date">
                            05.05.2005 
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="separator">
                        <th>
                            Na DVD
                             od:
                                                    </th>
                        <td class="date">
                            01.10.2005 Bonton
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

PHP code:

```
$ret = $html->find('td[class="date"]');

$kino = array();
foreach ($ret as $kino) {
    $datum[] = $datum->innertext;
    } 

   echo "$datum[0]";
```

I get not output from this and i have no idea whats wrong on my code.   I just want to get that DATEs (so should be 06.05.2005, 05.05.2005, 01.10.2005)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't load the html, look at this

```
$html = str_get_html('Some text bla bla bla bla<br /><b>Date</b>: 2012-12-13<br /><br /><b>Name</b>: Peter Novak<br /><b>Hobby</b>: books,cinema,facebook');
foreach($html->find('text') as $t){
    if(substr($t, 0, 1)==':')
    {
        // do whatever you want
        echo substr($t, 1).'<br />';
    }
}
```

Output will be

```
2012-12-13
Peter Novak
books,cinema,facebook
```

Also, check this one to load a remote site's content

```
$html = file_get_html('http://heera.it');
// Find all article blocks
foreach($html->find('div.post-entry') as $article) {
    echo $article->find('div.post-entry-content h2 a', 0) . '<br />';
    echo $article->find('div.post-entry-content p', 0)->plaintext. '<br />';
    echo "<hr />";
}
```

The result will be

[image]

Comment: i am getting lots of info so i didnt copy / paste whole script here, i get HTML already with:
$html = file_get_html('file.txt');